# Generator with memory leak

Tags: python, generator

I have following batch generator:

```
def batch_generator(X, Y, array_size, batch_size = 96):
    while True:
            p = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
            X = X[p]
            Y = Y[p]
            for i in range(array_size):
                start = i*batch_size
                end = start + batch_size + 1
                yield X[start:end], Y[start:end]
```

And this section each while cycle use more and more memory.

```
            p = np.random.permutation(X.shape[0])
            X = X[p]
            Y = Y[p]
```

How to solve this leak?

Function is called by:

```
batch_gen = batch_generator(
    L[:(size_of_dataset*BATCH_SIZE + 1)],
    ab[:(size_of_dataset*BATCH_SIZE + 1)],
    size_of_dataset,
    BATCH_SIZE
)
```

And then keras fit

```
model.fit(batch_gen ,epochs=500...)
```

From this output, we can see, how memory usage growing:

```
MEM USED: 34028564480
Epoch 1/500
MEM USED: 68172357632
MEM USED: 68327460864
MEM USED: 94857654272
597/597 - 111s - accuracy: 0.6081 - loss: 0.0767 - val_accuracy: 0.6318 - val_loss: 0.0744
Epoch 2/500
MEM USED: 101374386176
MEM USED: 112654151680
597/597 - 103s - accuracy: 0.6365 - loss: 0.0721 - val_accuracy: 0.6416 - val_loss: 0.0716
Epoch 3/500
MEM USED: 102938615808
MEM USED: 112201596928
597/597 - 105s - accuracy: 0.6443 - loss: 0.0698 - val_accuracy: 0.6280 - val_loss: 0.0700
Epoch 4/500
MEM USED: 104500965376
MEM USED: 112002859008
597/597 - 104s - accuracy: 0.6502 - loss: 0.0683 - val_accuracy: 0.6612 - val_loss: 0.0680
Epoch 5/500
MEM USED: 106063552512
MEM USED: 111480320000
597/597 - 107s - accuracy: 0.6558 - loss: 0.0666 - val_accuracy: 0.6469 - val_loss: 0.0673
Epoch 6/500
MEM USED: 107625590784
MEM USED: 110876241920
597/597 - 105s - accuracy: 0.6626 - loss: 0.0651 - val_accuracy: 0.6636 - val_loss: 0.0661
Epoch 7/500
```

Comment: How did you monitor the memory usage?

Comment: I added following lines to my script, before that, my script took 40-50 GB RAM. Now it took at init again 40-50 GB, but after each epoch +1 GB. So after 200 epochs it took 250 GB RAM.

Comment: How did you monitor the memory usage? Which tool? BTW it is great that you have such a large amount of RAM available on your system.

Comment: `del p` at the end of iteration?

Comment: @trincot monitoring using htop, it is GPU cluster

Comment: @AlexLarionov does not work

Comment: delete the original X and Y?

Comment: @drum i tried to override original X and Y with new permutation, but doesn't work ...

Comment: How do you call this function? What does the calling code do with the yielded values?

Comment: @trincot init `batch_gen = batch_generator(L[:(size_of_dataset*BATCH_SIZE + 1)], ab[:(size_of_dataset*BATCH_SIZE + 1)], size_of_dataset, BATCH_SIZE)` and then keras fit `model.fit(batch_gen ,epochs=500...)`

Comment: If you exclude the keras part, and just iterate over your generated values without doing anything with them, do you get the same memory usage? So: `for _ in batch_gen: pass`.

Comment: Try `batch_generator(X0, Y0,...` and `X = X0[p]`.  My guess is that repeated slicing by permutations is building up a chain.

Comment: @trincot it looks like without keras.fit there is not memory leak...

Comment: So, I think there is your answer. The memory consumption happens probably because keras.fit keeps the consumed values in memory and adds memory usage of its own. But we can't be sure. There is also the aspect of the garbage collector, whose behaviour is (Python)implementation dependent.

Comment: @trincot I dont know, when i tried without permutation, it works great...

Comment: Well it certainly is not the generator's fault: by the reassignments of all variables used, the previously referenced memory is released in each iteration for garbage collection. There is nothing more you can do. It is up to the garbage collector to deal with it.